# Android NDK, headers from a prebuilt static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, static-libraries

I am having a problem when using a pre-built static library when the compiler is looking for headers.

I have a .cpp that needs to use a header file from a static library. My Android.mk is as followed :

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := LibA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/libA.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello.cpp 
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES :=  LibA 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

hello.cpp requires a header that can be found in the static library but the compiler says it can't find it. Do I have to have headers seperated from that static library ?

Answer (score 1):

Headers are not included in static libraries. Even if they were, the compiler has no way to read a .a file, only the linker will do that.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify folder with include files from the library, using

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := <your folder>

in the Android.mk file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a prof, but I've learned that you *allways* need a corresponding .h-file
included! In those .h-files the compiler gets the info "how to use" the libraries
as they defines the functions that are inside the libs.

Good luck
Martin

Answer (score 0):

try "LOCAL_LDLIBS" in 2nd step.